# Running OLS on binary dependent variable

Tags: r, dplyr, lm

I have data such as this:

```
data_in <-read_table2("Condition    grade   block   Q2_1    Q2_2    Q2_4    Q2_8    Q2_10   Q2_11   Q2_14
Treatment   8   LB-MS-3 3   3   3   2   1   2   2
Treatment   9   LB-HS-2 4   4   4   3   3   4   3
Treatment   7   LB-MS-1 3   4   3   3   2   2   4
Treatment   10  LB-HS-2 2   4   2   3   3   3   3
Control 9   LB-HS-1 2   4   4   2   3   2   2
Control 8   LB-MS-3 3   3   3   2   3   3   2
Control 10  LB-HS-2 4   4   3   3   3   2   2
Control 8   LB-MS-1 3   3   3   3   2   3   3
Control NA  LB-MS-3 3   3   3   2   3   3   4
Control 8   LB-MS-1 4   4   4   4   3   3   3
Control 9   LB-HS-1 3   3   4   3   3   4   4
Treatment   NA  LB-MS-1 2   2   2   2   2   2   2
Treatment   8   LB-MS-1 3   3   3   2   2   2   2
Control 11  LB-HS-1 3   4   3   1   2   3   3
Treatment   10  LB-HS-1 3   4   2   2   3   4   3
Treatment   8   LB-MS-3 4   4   4   3   3   4   3
Control 7   LB-MS-3 4   2   3   2   3   2   2
Treatment   7   LB-MS-2 4   3   3   4   3   4   3
Control 7   LB-MS-3 3   3   3   2   2   2   3
Treatment   8   LB-MS-2 4   2   3   3   2   2   2
")
```

I would like to run "condition" as the binary dependent variable, and several numeric and character vars as independent variables. My expectation is that R will turn the character variables into dummy's for me.

```
model <- lm(condition~.,data=data_in)
summary(model)
```

However, I get NA's when I run this. I'm not very familiar with stats, so any help explanation is appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a specific programming question that's appropriate for Stack Overflow. If you have general questions about the appropriate use of various statistical methods, then you should ask such questions over at [stats.se] instead. You are more likely to get better answers there.

Comment: Do you need `glm` `data_in$Condition <- factor(data_in$Condition)#
> glm(Condition ~ ., data = na.omit(data_in), family = "binomial")`

Comment: @akrun. No need for `na.omit` as the default for `glm` and probably all R modelling functions is to omit NA.

Comment: @Edward i was testing with lm code and forgot to remove that na.omit

Comment: If you _really_ want to run OLS on a binary dependent variable, then turn the character variable into a 0/1 variable using `data_in$condition <- ifelse(data_in$condition=="Treatment", 1, 0)`. Your `lm` command should then run without error.

Answer (score 0):

it is not entirely clear that your Condition variable is binary. Typically, for binary variables they are coded between 0 and 1. Without compressing your Condition variable into two categories when it is really 4, for example, you would need to recode the variable to be 0 and 1. What are the different values for your Condition variable? You can see this by doing typing `tabulate(data_in$condition)`.

Say condition has two values, 3 and 4. You could recode these values to be 0 and 1 by doing the following.
`data_in$condition[data_in$condition == 3] <- 0`

`data_in$condition[data_in$condition == 4] <- 1`

As a conceptual point: binary measures are typically "yes", "no" measures where 0 represents a no instance and a 1 represents a yes instance. For example if you convert from a gender variable coded 1 for male and 2 for female, you'd create a female variable where you have 0 for male and 1 for female. This is a conceptual thing to think through for your variable.

If you would still like to continue, typically for binary dependent variables, you want to calculate the model using either a logit or a probit model (they have different interpretations than what you have for a lm (OLS) model, so I'd recommend reading some stats forums for that).

To run either a logit or probit in r, you can simply type:
`model <- glm(condition ~ IV1 + IV2 + IV3, family = binomial(link = "probit"), data = data_in)`

`summary(model)`

There are a few things to note. Here, instead of lm you are using the glm function which is nifty for using other generalized linear models besides OLS. You need to include your independent variables on the other side of the tilde. This is why your model didn't work before, you do not have any IVs to calculate a covariance  with your DV from. If you are running a probit model, you want to specify the link function you use which is a probit link function with a binomial distribution. If you use logit, then family will equal normal (because logit follows a logit-normal distribution, or a normal distribution) and will specify the link function 'link' to be equal to "logit".

EDIT: You can create a new variable for your condition variable.

`data_in$condition.num <- NA`

`data_in$condition.num <- ifelse(data_in$condition == "Control", 0, 1)`

Then run your Probit model:

`model <- glm(condition.num ~ grade + block + Q2_1, data = data_in, family = binomial(link = "probit"))`

`summary(model)`

Comment: Another thing I'd recommend doing, before you try to interpret your results, is to calculate your expected values or by making a graph using ggplot for this. You can find a lot of help for doing this by googling interpreting logit and probit results in r. Depending on what you are doing this for, you can get away with using a OLS model on a binary DV. There are some in-the-weeds discussions about how appropriate this is, but in some academic fields, OLS is typically okay since the parameters are easier to interpret. But, yeah, review some statistics before you do too much with this.